# Deploying windows forms project without installing .NET 4.0 client

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have made a windows forms application on VS2010 with .NET 4.0, Now its time to deploy on the client side, I was wondering if there is any way to make a setup that includes all the libs and dlls (of .NET framework) that will be needed at client side to run the application "without installing .NET 4.0 client/ framework" on the concerned node, what settings will be needed to do so.

Thanks in advance

MGD

Answer (score 6):

No, you need to deploy .net properly.

Comment: +1, though it's certainly possible to include .NET as a prerequisite (and include the installation files) for a Setup project.

Comment: @Adam Yes indeed, thanks, and of course that's how it is normally done.